# Where can I find the app package names for the Microsoft Store free-trial versions of Office 365 applications?

Tags: windows, ms-office, office365-apps

**Context**

I am looking to identify the app package names of trial versions of Microsoft Office applications *without* having them installed on my machine. These trial versions are downloaded from the Microsoft Store and are listed separately from full version Office 365 applications.

**Reiterating Question**

Without having the trial versions of the apps installed on my machine, *where can I find the app package names for the Microsoft Store, free trial versions of Office 365 applications?* (E.g., without using `get-appxpackage` since they don't exist on my machine)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot find these package names. They are inaccessible.